# If $|b_{n+1} - a_{n+1}| \leq |b_{n} - a_{n}| + \frac{1}{n}$ and $a_n \rightarrow a$, then $b_n$ converges and $b_n \rightarrow a$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Is it true that if $|b_{n+1} - a_{n+1}| \leq |b_{n} - a_{n}| + \frac{1}{n}$ and $a_n \rightarrow a$, then $b_n$ converges and $b_n \rightarrow a$?

Trying to prove it, we write
$|b_{n+1} - a| = |b_{n+1} - a_{n+1} + a_{n+1} - a| \leq |b_{n+1} - a_{n+1}| + | a_{n+1} - a| $. We know that the second term is as small as we wish, but what about the first term?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not true. With $c_n = b_n - a_n$ an equivalent formulation of your conjecture is

> Let $(c_n)$ be a sequence of real numbers with $|c_{n+1}| \le |c_n| + \frac 1n$ for all $n$. Does this imply $\lim_{n \to \infty} c_n = 0$?

which is wrong. Some counterexamples are

- $c_n = 0, 1, 1, 1, \ldots$, which is convergent, but not to zero.
- $c_n = \sin(\ln(n+1))$, which is bounded but not convergent (it “oscillates” between $-1$ and $1$).
- $c_n = 1 + \frac 12 + \cdots + \frac 1n$, which is not even bounded.